# My current header is does not work on mobile. How can I make my header responsive?

Tags: html, css, mobile-website, web-frontend

So, right now my header doesn´t look good on mobile. - The words overlap. They should remain in the same order... I tried to use `line-height`, which did not really change anything. Maybe you have some suggestions on how I can fix this problem. I am thankful for every suggestion!

[enter

```css
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 7vh;
    padding: 0 5%;
    color: white;
    font-size: larger;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:100;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 10px;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 4px 0;
    
}   

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 30px;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white; 
}

*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Menü {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" >
        <nav>
          <div>
          <a href="#Start"><Button class="ImageButton"> <input class="ImageButton" type="image" src="/Images/Camellion Logo Website.png"></Button></a>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <a class="Menü" href="/Galerie/Galerie.html">Galerie</a>
                <a class="Menü" href="#Leistungen">Leistungen</a>
                <a class="Menü" href="#Kontakt">Kontakt &amp; Standort   <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you want to make it responsive, you need to use media query for mobile screen size, then change its display from horizontally to vertically, then assign this change to a button using a burger menu to show and hide the menu. please learn and do your best then show us what have you tried then we can help. you  can start [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a thing in CSS called media queries. With media queries you can write for example CSS that only takes effect if screen is certain size.

For example

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 800px) {
    .header {
        height: 60px;
    }
}
```

Will set header height to 60px if the device that the page is opened on has screen width more then 360px and less then 800px.

Here is your code with couple adjustments

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    
    position: sticky;
    z-index:100;
    top: 0;
}

.navigation {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 80px;
    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu-icon { /* CSS to just to simulate Icon */
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 40px;
}

.menu-item {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap; /* Will not let words to break to next line */
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

@media(max-width: 600px) {
  .header { padding: 0 10px; }
  .navigation { height: 60px; }
  .menu { gap: 20px;}
  .menu-item { font-size: 14px; }
}

@media(max-width: 400px) {
  .menu { gap: 10px;}
  .menu-item { font-size: 12px; }
}
```

```html
<header class="header" >
  <nav class="navigation">
  
    <a href="#Start"><div class="menu-icon" title="Menu icon / hamburger icon"></div></a>

    <div class="menu">
        <a class="menu-item" href="/Galerie/Galerie.html">Galerie</a>
        <a class="menu-item" href="#Leistungen">Leistungen</a>
        <a class="menu-item" href="#Kontakt">Kontakt &amp; Standort <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i></a>
    </div>
    
  </nav>
</header>
```

You can adjust your css even further. It's very popular to have icons with menu elements and on mobile view they become a bottom navigation bar with big icons and tiny text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
   @media (max-width:767px) {
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

    nav {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    nav .Menu {
        margin-inline: 9px
    }
    }
```

good luck